# Flink Cluster Performance is much worse than standalone

Tags: hadoop, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I use flink to process HDFS files or local files.
When I use standalone setup, the server can process the data at 500k/s.
But when I use cluster，the server can only process the data at 100k/s.
It is so weird，I can not figure out what is going on.
I found that when I use cluster（2 servers), there is always one server which has low speeds to read/write data. The flink cluster is based on hadoop.
Can anyone help me？

Comment: I found the reason. Because of IO speed, the throughput is always low. In Flink one taskmanager is based on one JVM. The Slot means the thread in the taskmanager. The highest IO speed of server is 200M/s，but the Flink taskmanager JVM IO speed is only 60M/s. How can i improve the JVM IO Speed. Or if the JVM IO Speed is fixed in linux？

Comment: It sounds like you have to use servers that are better optimized for IO.